# Simple Harmonic Motion example

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, relative-motion

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalator

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion

Can we classify escalator device as a Simple Harmonic motion example?

Comment: Why do you think it might be?

Comment: The wiki article you ink has the mathematics of the simple harmonic motion. How do you think to fit it to the motion of the escalator?

Comment: An escalator may have different kinds of motion. You should clarify which of them you are considering as SHM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, **NOT**. In simple harmonic motion, restoring force is acting which tries to return object back into equilibrium state. Thus object is never at equilibrium, if dissipation forces would be ignored. Escalator is always at equilibrium, it can be seen when motors are stopped - escalator stops immediately at close position where it was before. Besides due to harmonic oscillation object moves with acceleration and deceleration, which here is not the case. Hypothetically if escalator would be *perfectly circular*, then tangential speed of wheel would give one-dimensional simple harmonic oscillator when projected onto some $x$ coordinate axis. But usually escalators are not round, for they try to optimize number of loaded people. So all in all, NO, escalator is not a simple harmonic motion in any sense.

Answer (score -2):

For a particle to execute SHM its motion should be periodic and osscilatory.
For the escalators its motion is periodic but not oscillatory